# How does one detect if one is running within a docker container within Python?

Tags: python, docker

I was trying to find out if my script was running inside a docker container or not within the python script.

Something like:

```
if inside_docker():
    do_stuff()
else:
    do_some_other_stuff()
```

to do this the only hacky way I found out how to do it is that I can inspect the hostname (with  `platform.node()`) and if the hostname is not the same as my computer then its not in docker (since hostnames docker are some weird hash or something).

Instead I was thinking something a bit more programatic as follows:

1. first detect docker with `cat /proc/1/cgroup`
2. then compare the name those hierarchies with the docker id/hash.

Something like:

```
from subprocess import call
import platform
hash = call('cat /proc/1/cgroup')
hostname = hostname = platform.node()
docker_boolean = does_hostname_contain_docker_hash(hash, hostname) # true or false
```

I thought something like that would work but I can't even get to call the `cat /proc/1/cgroup` without an error. If I am in docker I get the error:

```
>>> from subprocess import call
>>> call('from subprocess import call')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 523, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

any ideas how to fix that?

---

as a side node I was thinking of making my solution portable but docker is suppose to be portable already so if I am in docker this should always work...

Comment: What if you fed an environment variable to your container? That way your python app would only be able to retrieve it if it was running in the container.

Comment: or even better I could just have that environment be defined in the docker file, I don't want to have to pass something weird to every container I ever use XD

Comment: Can you tell us the use case? Will you always have control over the execution context? To be honest if you don't, there is absolutely no way (user could 'game / trick' any one of the methods / answers).

Comment: @johnharris85 its just to be able to specify to the script where the data files are when I run it locally vs using docker in a cluster.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I think the preferred way to do this is through environment variables. If you're creating your Python app from a Dockerfile, you could specify the 'ENV' directive:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env

Dockerfile:

```
...
ENV AM_I_IN_A_DOCKER_CONTAINER Yes
```

which could then be read from your app with something like:

python_app.py:

```
import os

SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('AM_I_IN_A_DOCKER_CONTAINER', False)

if SECRET_KEY:
    print('I am running in a Docker container')
```

Comment: Small detail, but `SECRET_KEY` will always evaluate to `True` if the default is `'NOPE'`.

Comment: To me more favor for a simpler approach right from python code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48710609/248616)

Comment: In Dockerfile: `ENV CONTAINER=1`

In Python code: `os.environ.get("CONTAINER", "").lower() in ("yes", "y", "on", "true", "1")`

Answer (score 42):

The [is-docker package for npm](https://github.com/sindresorhus/is-docker/blob/master/index.js) suggests a robust approach, ported here to Python 2.6+:

```
import os
def is_docker():
    def text_in_file(text, filename):
        try:
            with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as lines:
                return any(text in line for line in lines)
        except OSError:
            return False
    cgroup = '/proc/self/cgroup'
    return os.path.exists('/.dockerenv') or text_in_file('docker', cgroup)
```

Comment: I assume that this is run within the running docker image. Correct?

Comment: @vpap if it is running outside of the dockar image the function will return `False`

Comment: I used this but removed the check for /.dockerenv

Comment: I get:
unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/proc/self/cgroup' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>

Comment: @Jason R. Coombs: Can you please fix this answer? Your module also uses Pathlib.Path:
from jaraco.docker import is_docker

Comment: I've updated the implementation to address the ResourceWarning and EncodingWarning that might be emitted on later Pythons. See [here](https://gist.github.com/jaraco/e25faf6a06ca664c4e946075d485a4fe) for it in action. Note that I did not update to use pathlib.Path, since the answer specifically indicates Python 2.6+.

Answer (score 11):

In Python 3.4+ this should work nice

```
from pathlib import Path

def is_docker():
    cgroup = Path('/proc/self/cgroup')
    return Path('/.dockerenv').is_file() or cgroup.is_file() and 'docker' in cgroup.read_text()
```

Comment: This is amazingly succinct and simple. Perfect, thank you!

Comment: This solution did not work for me. Running a docker container the return statement evaluated to: ```False or True and False```. I am also not sure wheather there should be braces around the ```or``` operator like ```(False or True) and False```? See also: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Answer (score 10):

```
import os, re

path = "/proc/self/cgroup"

def is_docker():
  if not os.path.isfile(path): return False
  with open(path) as f:
    for line in f:
      if re.match("\d+:[\w=]+:/docker(-[ce]e)?/\w+", line):
        return True
    return False

print(is_docker())
```

Comment: This would fail if `--pid=host` is used (i.e, if the container shares the PID namespace with the host).  To make it work your code needs a minimal change:
`path = "/proc/" + os.getpid() + "/cgroup"`

Comment: This technique isn't working for me. I'm using docker for mac. The lines in `/proc/12/cgroup` include things like : `13:name=systemd:/docker-ce/docker/3ee...\n`. The regex misses due to the `=` in second field and the `/docker-ce` in the third field.

Comment: @JasonR.Coombs that should cover the old and new layouts now

Comment: There is a magic `/proc/self` symlink pointing to the right PID, so you don't need to call `os.getpid()`, but can let kernel do the work inside path resolution directly.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to the is-docker package for npm, I've created [jaraco.docker](https://pypi.org/project/jaraco.docker) with an `is_docker` function. For Python 3.5+ with that package installed:

```
from jaraco.docker import is_docker
if is_docker():
    print("In docker")
```

Comment: Yeah, it's been 3 years. Not working in 2020 :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean it's not working. [Works great for me](https://gist.github.com/638896dfeff10074baa971e70cd2916f) and there are [no issues filed with the project](https://github.com/jaraco/jaraco.docker/issues). Also, it's 2021.

Comment: Haha, right. I always forgot about new year! Yeah, sorry, when I tried it, got error. But then I realize I can simply supply env variable saying, IN_DOCKER. So, I use that

Comment: To me more favor for a simpler approach right from python code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48710609/248616)

Comment: I'm not sure it's simpler for each and every potential user to make a copy/paste of the code. Of course, any user is welcome to do so, but if there's a bug in the original source or if the technique needs to evolve for changes in Docker, then all of the copies will need to get updated. It seems simpler in the long run to provide an implementation with a single source of truth and mechanism for updating.

Comment: Case in point, [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48710609/70170) grew stale and yet aims to maintain compatibility with a long retired Python. Compare that with `jaraco.docker` which has been able to shed legacy concerns and address emergent issues on later Pythons (even for a 20 line library) across every user who uses it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment directly on [fenceop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2202669/fenceop)'s comment under https://stackoverflow.com/a/43879407/6075474, but I'd like to provide just a touch deeper insight. One could overcome the behavior they mention of `if SECRET_KEY` being truthy in the event of `SECRET_KEY='NOPE'` by instead doing

```py
...
if SECRET_KEY is True:
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nodeJS

[is-docker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-docker) is a popular npm packages to accomplish this.

```js
import isDocker from 'is-docker';

if (isDocker()) {
    console.log('Running inside a Docker container');
}
```

Comment: The OP is about python, so 
To me more favor for a simpler approach right from python code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48710609/248616)